# webpack including react 0.14-beta2 twice in final bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0-beta1"}
```

index.js

```
var React = require('react'),
     ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
```

webpack config

```
 entry: {
        mainpage: './index.js'
    },
```

**Edit :**

```
npm install react-dom@0.14.0-beta2 --save // solved my issue
```

Comment: You probably have a dependency that has ReactJS as a dependency and the versions are not matching.

Comment: hmm no, that's my whole index.js file

Comment: @invariant Can you mark your edit as answer and mark it accepted? Thanks. :)

Comment: @bebraw done , thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install react-dom@0.14.0-beta2 --save // solved my issue
```